# design servlet router from scratch

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters

I want to design a url router based on servlets.

Router will typically takes a web request to proper controller and action.

Web urls will be of "controller/action" pattern.

What I tried:

1. Pattern: /controller?action=dosomething
2. url mapping will take flow to servlet.
3. servlet will create instance of controller
4. "action" GET parameter will execute method on controller using reflection.

What I did is lame. I want url to be of "controller/action" form.

Some pointers would be helpful.

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Design Patterns web based applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications)

Answer (score 2):

The servlet specification gives a nice explanation with examples

Here's a rewritten part of it:

If you have a webapp whose context path is `/catalog`, and a servlet mapped to `/lawn/*`, and if a request comes in for the path `/catalog/lawn/index.html`, the ContextPath of the request will be /catalog; its ServerPath will be `/lawn`, and its PathInfo will be `/index.html`.

Use the ServerPath and ContextPath properties of the request to extract the controller part and the action part of the URL.

Comment: what url mapping will you use in web.xml? Is there catch-all servlet with path "*.*"..If it is "*.*" then when I try to load jsp again this catch-all servlet is invoked.

Comment: You are the one who should decide, since you chose to reimplement an MVC framework from scratch, although plenty of excellent ones already exist.

Comment: If I try to  dispatch jsp catch-all servlet is invoked. How to exclude jsp from catch-all servlet?